# web services within IPv6 network protocol

Tags: soa, ipv6

Does SOA(Service Oriented Architecture) works properly within IPv6 network deployments? Are the freely existing tools(eg. eclipse, netbeans etc) to create web services takes care of IPv6 network addresses?

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 works at layer 3, while SOA and applications work at layer 7, so that should be no problem. Not all applications and libraries are properly written though, so there might be implementation specific limitations. Tools like Eclipse and Netbeans work equally well for IPv4 and IPv6. They don't really care about the IP version.